# How can we get web chat logs?

Tags: web, twilio, twilio-api

We can get SMS & Call logs using these url

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC12345/Messages.csv?PageSize=1000

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC12345/Calls.csv?PageSize=1000

But how we can get webchat logs?